# Android Custom ListView and alertDialog - Custom GridView

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, listview, gridview

Добрый день, имеется адаптер для listview в нем при нажатии на imageView в элементе списка вызывается alertDialog в котором EditView и GridView, тоже кастомный который фильтруется EditView

```
final TextWatcher inputTxt = new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s.toString().toLowerCase() + "+.+");
                            int k = 0;
                            for (String el:arr) {
                                Matcher m = p.matcher(el);
                                if (m.matches()) {
                                    arr.add(el);
                                }
                            }
                            arr= arr.toArray(new String[0]);
                            GridViewAdapter newGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.el, arr);
                            allHero.setAdapter(newGridAdapter);


                        } else {
                            arr= mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arr);
                            GridViewAdapter newGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(mContext, R.layout.el, arr);
                            allHero.setAdapter(newGridAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                };
                editText.addTextChangedListener(inputTxt);
```

Но клику на элемент GridView срабатывает -

```
boolean isUsed = false;

                        for (El el: arr) {
                            if (el!= null && el.Name.equals(arr[pos])) {
                                isUsed = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if(!isUsed) {
                            arr[_this] = new El(arr[pos], mContext);
                            mHolder.heroPortret.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),heroList[_this].Avatar));
                            mHolder.heroLvl.setText(heroList[_this].lvl + mContext.getString(R.string.lvl));

                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        } else{
                            String name = heroes[pos].replace("_"," ");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                            builder.setTitle("Важное сообщение!")
                                    .setMessage(name.toUpperCase()+" уже в игре!")
                                    .setPositiveButton("ОК", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            // Закрываем окно
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            builder.show();
                        }
```

Тут происходит ошибка, изображение кладется в другой элемент listview (визуально) т.е. нажал на второй элемент, а при возврате заполнился третий.

Срабатывает такой баг только если фильровать GridView, без фильтрации все кладется куда нужно.

Может ли регулярка так действовать на список?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Регулярные выражения не могут влиять на Grid. Влияют ошибки в логике работы

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
....
for (String el:arr) {
```

Вы перебираете пустой массив.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s.toString().toLowerCase() + "+.+");
```

Допустим, введен текст `hero`, тогда регулярка `hero+.+`- что-то с ней не то.

Ищите ошибки в логике.